# Extremely large text file manipulation (adding a column; changing contents of column)

Tags: awk, columns

I have a set of very large (80GB) files (genomic variants dosage) which are ".txt.gz" at the moment and have the following layout (columns/variables):

> > Chr RSID POS REF ALT Ind1 Ind2...Ind(n) where 1:n are individuals

I would like to edit this file such that:

1. the Chr column/variable is set to a specific chromosome number (e.g., 3) for all rows
2. there is a new column inserted into the file at a specific spot (I would like the new column/variable to be inserted between ALT and Ind1...such that the new column would be the 6th column in edited file). I would also like the value of this column to be set to a constant (e.g., 0).

Finally, I would like to output the edited file in the same format as it was read in (therefore, output should be ".txt.gz"

I appreciate any help and would be happy to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncompress the file, pass the uncompressed data stream to `awk`,  let `awk` do the modification, and pass the stream on to `gzip` for compression.

```bsh
gzip -c -d <file.txt.gz |
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $1 = 3; $6 = 0 OFS $6 }; 1' |
gzip -c >newfile.txt.gz
```

The `awk` command sets its input field separator (`FS`) and the output field separator (`OFS`) to a tab character.
It then sets the first field to `3` and the 6th field to `0`, followed by a tab and the old 6th field.

The lone `1` at the very end of the `awk` script causes the modified data to be output.

The input to `awk` is the decompressed stream of data from `gzip -d`, and the output from `awk` goes through `gzip` for compression.

If the data has a header row that we need to modify separately:

```bsh
gzip -c -d <file.txt.gz |
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    NR == 1 {         $6 = "NEW" OFS $6 }
    NR != 1 { $1 = 3; $6 = 0     OFS $6 }; 1' |
gzip -c >newfile.txt.gz
```

Here we do things differently depending on the input line number.  If we're on line 1, we insert the header `NEW` as the header for the new 6th field.  If we're not on line 1, we modify the data as before.

You can also do this with `sed`, but as you tagged the question with `awk` I'm assuming that is the tool you prefer to use.

Comment: This is very helpful, and it worked seamlessly! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to work on gawk, mawk-1, mawk-2, and nawk :

```
(…gunzip…)\
 \
 |  mawk 'BEGIN { _+=___=_+=(__=_^=OFS=FS="\t")+_ }\
                $_=(__==NR?"NEW":_<($__=___))FS $_'\
 | (…re-gzip…)
```